# Super-sampling anti-aliasing for a curve via libpng

Tags: c, antialiasing, libpng

I tried to smoothen a line via the super-sampling anti-aliasing technique by adding transparency to neighboring pixels. Here is the code in C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <png.h>

#define WIDTH 512
#define HEIGHT 512

int main()
{
    // Image buffer
    unsigned char image[HEIGHT][WIDTH][4];

    for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++)
        {
            image[i][j][0] = 255;
            image[i][j][1] = 255;
            image[i][j][2] = 255;
            image[i][j][3] = 0;
        }
    }

    // A sample curve
    for (double x = -M_PI; x <= M_PI; x += M_PI / WIDTH)
    {
        int y = (int)(HEIGHT / 2 - sin(x) * cos(x) * HEIGHT / 2);
        int i = (int)(x * WIDTH / (2 * M_PI) + WIDTH / 2);

        // The anti-aliasing part
        int sample = 2; // how far we are sampling
        double max_distance = sqrt(sample * sample + sample * sample);
        for (int ii = -sample; ii <= sample; ii++)
        {
            for (int jj = -sample; jj <= sample; jj++)
            {
                int iii = i + ii;
                int jjj = y + jj;
                if (iii >= 0 && iii < WIDTH && jjj >= 0 && jjj < HEIGHT)
                {
                    // Here is my question
                    int alpha = 255 - (int)(100.0 * sqrt(ii * ii + jj * jj) / max_distance);
                    image[jjj][iii][0] = 0;
                    image[jjj][iii][1] = 0;
                    image[jjj][iii][2] = 0;
                    image[jjj][iii][3] = alpha > image[jjj][iii][3] ? alpha : image[jjj][iii][3];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    FILE *fp = fopen("curve.png", "wb");
    png_structp png = png_create_write_struct(PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    png_infop info = png_create_info_struct(png);
    png_init_io(png, fp);
    png_set_IHDR(png, info, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 8, PNG_COLOR_TYPE_RGBA, PNG_INTERLACE_NONE,
                 PNG_COMPRESSION_TYPE_BASE, PNG_FILTER_TYPE_BASE);
    png_write_info(png, info);
    for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++)
    {
        png_write_row(png, (png_bytep)image[i]);
    }
    png_write_end(png, NULL);
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Although it does some smoothing, but the result is far from the available programs. Where did I do wrong?

I tried to calculate the transparency based on the distance of each neighboring pixel from the center of the line:

```
int alpha = 255 - (int)(100.0 * sqrt(ii * ii + jj * jj) / max_distance);
```

I used the factor of 100 instead of 255 since we do not need to go deep into full transparency.

The problem is how to set the alpha value for each pixel based on neighboring pixels when the transparency of each neighbor is subject to change according to its neighbors?

Comment: The question is good, but be aware there are a limited number that will have specific knowledge about smoothing "via the super-sampling anti-aliasing technique". That doesn't take away from the question, but understand an answer may take longer to appear than with  general programming questions.

Comment: Not seeing how this is an example of supersampling. What kind of curves do you need to draw?

Comment: @Ry- you're right. The aim is supersampling, not the code. I seek a general solution for any sort of line (straight or with curvature). I used a periodic one as an example.

Comment: But are they all parametric? How about approximating with rectangles (i.e. lines with thickness)? For an initial memory-inefficient approach, you can have a bit for each supersampled point, toggle it on when it’s inside any line, and create the final result from that.

Comment: @Ry- line with thickness is a great idea. We can calculate the pixels within the line thickness. This way, we create more black pixels, but still how do we calculate the gray pixels outside the line?

Comment: That’s where the supersampling comes in. You have a set of samples that contribute to each pixel, decide whether or not each of them is covered according to the lines. Then the colour of each pixel is a function of the samples. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersampling#Supersampling_patterns